# Weird List Indentation

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I was making a simple menu in html/css and there was a weird indentation on the side that I can't seem to get rid of.

HTML:

```
<center><div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Videos</li>
    <li>Info</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    #menu ul {
        background-color:#F60;
        display:inline-block;
        border-bottom:5px solid #98FF00;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    #menu ul li {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:2px 2px 0 2px;
        padding:5px 5px 0 5px;
        background-color:#98ff00;
        transition:background-color 0.5s;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#F60;
    }
    #menu ul li:hover {
        background-color:#74C100;
    }
```

I have included a link to the fiddle where I am having the problem.

Thanks!

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRA0007/4anrq8Lj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `padding-left: 0` to the `ul`.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb907jwu/3/)

The reason for this is that browsers have some default styles for each element.  For `ul` elements, it defaults to having a padding-left of some amount (20px on Chrome I think).

A common practice for this kind of thing in web development is to start your style sheets with a ["reset"](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), i.e. reverting all of the browser defaults.